# How can I change the speed of a video?

Tags: video, editing

I have some clips of a sunrise, sunset, traffic that each last around an hour. How can I change the speed of these videos so that the one-hour video lasts only one minute? (That is, I want to create time lapse videos.)

Answer (score 4):

[slowmoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/index.html) is able to speed up and slow down video

> slowmoVideo is an OpenSource program that creates slow-motion videos
>   from your footage.
>
> But it does not simply make your videos play at 0.01× speed. You can
>   smoothly slow down and speed up your footage, optionally with motion
>   blur.
>
> How does slow motion work? slowmoVideo tries to find out where pixels
>   move in the video (this information is called Optical Flow), and then
>   uses this information to calculate the additional frames.

First [download](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php) and install the program. When it is loaded go to File > New and select your video file.

[image]

With your video loaded draw you curves (by clicking on an empty area) to describe how the video should speed up and slow down.

[image]

When you have finished go to File > Render (Ctrl + R) and choose a directory to save your video

[image]

Comment: Additionally, take a look at this solution using Blender http://askubuntu.com/a/31802/6689

Answer (score 3):

[kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) can do this as well: Use the Effects -> Motion -> Speed  Parameters are described here: https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Effects/Motion/Speed