# How to speed up video footage to make a timelapse video?

Tags: video

I've taken footage of sunsets and traffic etc and would like to make my hour long footage last only 30secs or so, what software can I use to perform this.
Thank you for your time. 
Phil

Comment: Have you tried PiTiVi? It is included by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the speed of a video?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134576/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-a-video)

Comment: @pl1nk the name of the according pitivi filter is … ? I can't find any.

Answer (score 4):

### **Avidemux**

(has GUI for both GTK and QT). (see Video->Frame Rate in application menu)

[image: Install via the software center]

You could also try [Virtualdub](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/)

Sorry for that last comment it was the wrong link.  Also [take a look at this](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=92582) to see if it helps.

Comment: Could you describe how to do that exactly with Avidemux?

Answer (score 4):

Just use ffmpeg - GUI programs always get outdated almost instantly

```
ffmpeg -i [input video] -filter:v "setpts=[RATIO]*PTS" [output video]
```

Here you have to replace [RATIO] with the number you get by dividing the duration (in seconds) of the output video with the duration of the input video. So if your traffic video original file is named traffic.webm and you want to name your output traffic-timelapse.webm the command would be (note that 30/(60*60) = 0.0008333 ):

```
ffmpeg -i traffic.webm -filter:v "setpts=0.0008333*PTS" traffic-timelapse.webm
```

Comment: What does -filter:v does? I have avconv, and it's pretty similar, but I haven't found this option in the documentation. In the end, I have a video where the video goes faster, but not the sound, and the "total time" displayed by VLC is the same as the input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **`slowmoVideo`** for the purpose.
The description of the software from their site:

> *"slowmoVideo is an OpenSource program that creates slow-motion videos from your footage. But it does not simply make your videos play at
>   0.01× speed. You can smoothly slow down and speed up your footage, optionally with motion blur."*

You can find the latest Ubuntu build of this application at:
http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/builds.php

Comment: @Jakob, Yes that's true. But as the application's description clearly says, it can also be used to `speed up the footage`.

Comment: oh, sorry! Could you describe how to do that?

Comment: Not available for Ubuntu 14 (and Mint 17).

Answer (score 3):

Kdenlive also has a video speed effect.

Comment: @DracNoc I recommend editing this answer to provide more information, or at least a link, for information about how to install Kdenlive and how to use its video speed effect.

Comment: Under Effects -> Motion -> Speed you can set a speedup: https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Effects/Motion/Speed